# Curl command on node-red

Tags: curl, node-red

Could anyone suggest me a way to transform a **curl** command such as "**curl ip:port/a/b -H myHeader1 -H myHeader2 -d '{... JSON FORMAT FILE ...}'** " which returns a reply on JSON format on a **node-red** flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HTTP Request` node can be used to make... http requests.

You can pass the node a `msg.headers` property that contains the HTTP headers to include in the request, and `msg.payload` will be sent as the body of the request.

Assuming the response contains the appropriate `content-type` header, the resulting `msg.payload` will be the JSON parsed into a JavaScript object.

You can see some more examples of the node in the Node-RED cookbook: http://cookbook.nodered.org/http/

Comment: Good explanation and very useful examples on Node-RED cookbook.

Comment: @james2017 if this has answered your question please consider accepting it

Comment: not clear how to put -d '{... JSON FORMAT FILE ...}'  into http request, and no examples on cookbook